# How do I force a higher resolution on Windows 7?

Tags: resolution

I have a laptop, and I want to force the native screen to display 1080p. I know the display driver is capable of that because I have connected it to a 1080p screen before and it worked.
I am doing this because I want to establish a remote connection from my Raspberry Pi to the laptop. The Pi (an ARM linux machine) is connected to the 1080p screen. At the moment, the remote connection only covers part of the screen, as the laptop is only displaying 1366x768 (or something).

I want a software solution, if possible. Also, I want a server-side solution (that is, on the windows machine) as finding and using Linux software that works on the pi is a bit of a nightmare!

I am using TightVNC, though am prepared to try any package is free and which works well, as a server for Windows and client for ARM Linux.

Solutions I have tried that don't work:

'show all modes' on control panel (still didn't show the mode 1920x1080, which I know the graphics adapter can do)

ZoneScreen OS (wouldn't let me create a higher resolution)

Demoforge Mirage (um... didn't do anything. Maybe I didn't get how you're supposed to use it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To force the raspberry pi to have a certain display. Go on boot folder `cd /boot/` 
After that, open the config file with your editor (I use geany `sudo apt-get install geany`)

```
sudo geany config.txt
```

In this file, it should have two line that you have to uncomment it:

```
framebuffer_width=800
framebuffer_height=600
```

Just change the values of those variables and save the file.
You may have to reboot your raspberry pi

Comment: Sorry, the issue is I need to force the WINDOWS machine to output a higher resolution than it will permit me to.